# Yield multiple items using scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm scraping data from the following URL:
http://www.indexmundi.com/commodities/?commodity=gasoline

There are two sections which contain price: **Gulf Coast Gasoline Futures End of Day Settlement Price** and **Gasoline Daily Price**

I want to scrape data from both sections as two different **items**. Here is the code which I've written:

```
if dailyPrice:
        item['description'] = u''.join(dailyPrice.xpath(".//h1/text()").extract())
        item['price'] = u''.join(dailyPrice.xpath(".//span/text()").extract())
        item['unit'] =  dailyPrice.xpath(".//div/p/text()").extract()[0].split(',')[-1]
        regex = re.compile("Source:(.*)",re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE)
        result = re.search(regex, u''.join(dailyPrice.xpath(".//div/p/text()").extract()))
        if result:
            item['source'] = result.group(1).strip()

        yield item


if futurePrice:
        item['description'] = u''.join(futurePrice.xpath(".//h1/text()").extract())
        item['price'] = u''.join(futurePrice.xpath(".//span/text()").extract())
        item['unit'] =  u''.join(futurePrice.xpath(".//div[2]/table//tr[1]/td/text()").extract())
        source = futurePrice.xpath(".//div[2]/table//tr[4]/td/a/text()").extract()
        if source:
            item['source'] = u' - '.join(source)
        else:
            item['source'] = ''

        yield item
```

I want to know if this code will work fine or what should be correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work just fine. You can yield as many items from a `parse` callback as you need. Just some notes:

1. In the second case it's better to create a new item then reusing the old one. Because you never know what has happened to the old item reference. Maybe you are overwriting and losing the previous data.
2. You can create different item types for your two cases. And in the pipeline treat them differently.

Comment: The reason for not creating the new item is that both items need to share some field values e.g url and a couple of more fields. I'm setting the values of those fields somewhere above this code and then setting the values of rest of the fields based on these two IF conditions and yielding items.

Comment: If two different items share the same data, use `copy.copy` to copy the first item and then update it.