# Scrapy Doesn't Scrape Bold Text

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been working on this spider for months now and have been stuck at the same problem- can anyone help me out?

On the mentioned website (see below), all of the instrument data is scraped EXCEPT for the bold "model names." This is infuriating, and I'm at a loss as far as what do to.

```
import re
import json
from urlparse import urlparse


from scrapy.selector import Selector
try:
    from scrapy.spider import Spider
except:
    from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider as Spider
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from database.items import databaseItem

from scrapy.log import *

class CommonSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'brands.py'
    allowed_domains = ['usedprice.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.usedprice.com/items/guitars-musical-instruments/index.html']

    rules = (

        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=( )), callback='parse_item'),
    )


    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = databaseItem()
        datao = datao = hxs.xpath('//tr[@class="oddItemColor baseText"]')
        datae = datae = hxs.xpath('//tr[@class="evenItemColor baseText"]')
        tmpNextPage = hxs.xpath('//div[@class="baseText blue"]/span[@id="pnLink"]/a/@href').extract()
        for attr in datao:
            *modelInfo = attr.xpath('.//b/text()').extract()*
            instrInfo = attr.xpathxpath('.//td//text()').extract()
            item['modelInfo'].append = modelInfo
            item['instrInfo'].append = instrInfo
            return databaseItem(modelInfo = modelInfo[1:], instrInfo = instrInfo[2:])
        for attr in datae:
            *modelInfo = attr.xpath('.//b/text()').extract()*
            instrInfo = attr.xpath('.//td//text()').extract()
            item['modelInfo'].append = modelInfo
            item['instrInfo'].append = instrInfo
            return databaseItem(modelInfo = modelInfo[1:], instrInfo = instrInfo[2:])
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, add the code for *databaseItem* so we can test the code without writing stubs. Also, make it clear what line exactly should get the text, how the result should look, and how it looks now. This way, I don't care to do the debugging from the start. Knowing the Xpath that is the problem reduces the debugging multiple times.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed my mistakes and italicized the lines which should grab model names.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

- use exact array indices (instead of slices) to pick up the `modelInfo` field

  - `[0][1:] == []`
- `yield` each `databaseItem` instead of returning it

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21672898
- add some logic to detect whether or not the bolded text is actually what you want

  - every second row in the table of interest has "Description" bolded, and no "column" for the "Type" information

(I haven't run your code, but I did look at http://www.usedprice.com/items/guitars-musical-instruments/a-basses/index.html )